# how to split complex string into parts?

Tags: javascript, variables, split

i have a variable in javascript like:

```
var str = DE10494570208;
var result = str.split(" ",2);
```

with my logic me getting:

> DE,10,49,45,70,20,8

i need just a value between DE and last 5 digits as: **104945**
how to get it with javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
str.substring(2,str.length-5);
```

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k2dge/)

Answer (score 2):

Regex solution:

```
str.match(/^.{2}(.+).{5}$/)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with str.match

```
"DE10494570208".match(/.{1,2}/g);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qNMW4/

Comment: That would give the same result as the OP currently has, which is not what they want.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
var str   = "DE10494570208";
var result = str.substr(2, str.indexOf("5")-1);
```